# How to convert string to array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, string

Actually, I am receiving array in response with slashes so, I did this.

what I receiving on the response

```
[{\"name\":\"title\",\"value\":\"%post_title%\"},{\"name\":\"author\",\"value\":\"%author_name%\"}]
```

so I did this

```
var b=JSON.stringify(response.data);
var str = b.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

after this, I have a string like

```
["{"name":"title","value":"%post_title%"}","{"name":"author","value":"%author_name%"}","{"name":"wordcount","value":"%wordcount%"}","{"name":"logged_in","value":"%logged_in%"}","{"name":"page_id","value":"%page_id%"}","{"name":"post_date","value":"%post_date%"}"]
```

now, how can I again covert this to the array so I use it in ng-repeat?

Comment: You want to try JSON.parse

Comment: sorry, i don't know about JSON.parse, if I use that can I convert string as an array ? can you give an example here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `JSON.parse()` to create an array:

```js
let str = '[{\"name\":\"title\",\"value\":\"%post_title%\"},{\"name\":\"author\",\"value\":\"%author_name%\"}]';

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse for that.

```
const myNewArray = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `angular.fromJson()`

```
$scope.x = '[{\"name\":\"title\",\"value\":\"%post_title%\"},{\"name\":\"author\",\"value\":\"%author_name%\"}]';

 console.log(angular.fromJson($scope.x));
```

otherwise use `JSON.parse()`

```
console.log(JSON.parse($scope.x));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JSON.parse()`:

```
var array = JSON.parse(`[
    {"name":"title",  "value":"%post_title%"}, 
    {"name":"author", "value":"%author_name%"}
]`);
```